# how to fix url with htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a url which initially http://web.com/index.php/home/funct/ and I want to change this by removing the index.php so that it becomes http://web.com/home/funct/

Comment: Have a look at [this very good website](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php). If you have a go, and then get stuck, someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Apache server, create a file called `.htaccess` and put this in it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Then just remove the reference to "/index.php/" from your links and when the server doesn't find "home/funct" it will go looking for "/index.php/home/funct".